# Delete duplicated record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains a lot of duplicated rows like this:

```
 id_emp  id       date      ch_in        ch_out
    1   34103   2019-09-01      
    1   34193   2019-09-01  17:00
    1   34194   2019-09-02  07:03:21    16:59:26
    1   34104   2019-09-02  07:03:21    16:59:26
    1   33361   2019-09-02  NULL        NULL
```

I want just one row for each date and others must delete with condition like I want the output must be:

```
       id_emp  id       date      ch_in        ch_out
        1   34193   2019-09-01  17:00
        1   34104   2019-09-02  07:03:21    16:59:26
```

I tried to use distinct but nothing working:

```
select  distinct id_emp, id, date_1, ch_in,ch_out
from ch_inout
where id_emp=1 order by date_1 asc
```

And I tried too using this query to delete:

```
select *
from (
  select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by date_1 order by id)
  from ch_inout 
) x
where rn > 1;
```

But nothing is working the result is empty.

Comment: How are you determining which `id` to return?  What is `num`?  It is not in your data.

Comment: num is unique field

Comment: @programmer_25, this is baffling, i thought you want to delete? and your unique Id is `num`?

Comment: I edit it to id not num thanks for your helping to me

Comment: you accepted an answer before editing.

Comment: Sorry sir i did not attention if you could right it and i will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id_emp, max(id) as id, date, min(ch_in), max(ch_out)
from ch_inout
group by id_emp, date;
```

This returns the maximum `id` for each group of rows.  That is  not exactly what is returned in the question, but you don't specify the logic.

EDIT:

If you want to delete all but the largest id for each `id_emp`/`date` combination, you can use:

```
delete c from ch_inout c
    where id < (select max(c2.id)
                from ch_inout c2
                where c2.id_emp = c.id_emp and c2.date = c.date
               );
```

Comment: @programmer_25, this is baffling, i thought you want to delete? and your unique Id is `num`?

Comment: Yes i want to delete but i will save this result in table and delete this one and i will back again insert again the right rows

Comment: and why are you doing that? while you can directly delete

Comment: How ? to do in this query : select id_emp, max(id) as id, date, min(ch_in), max(ch_out)
from ch_inout
group by id_emp, date; , i tried to write delete but it could not work

Comment: @programmer_25 . . . You can't.  You are probably best off saving the results in a temporary table, truncating the original table and re-inserting the values.

Comment: Okay i will do that thanks for your time to help me

Comment: @programmer_25, This is still not an answer to your question, you should ask something like "select duplicated records"

Comment: @GordonLinoff, your `select` and `delete` script will yield different results.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , It is working 100% thanks again for your effort .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the records you want to delete. Assuming that you want to keep the record with the lowest `id` on each `date`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM ch_inout t
) x
WHERE rn > 1
```

You can easily turn this into a `DELETE` statement:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM ch_inout t
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: I tried as your query and still duplicated , it is strange !